# Postgres acummulates disk I/O

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.6

I have a problem with postgres blocking my SSD (256MB) as it accumulates over time.

My application has a table with `caseA - caseB` pairs which I create beforehand. Using parallel workers, each worker with its own connection runs a select query - joins couple of other tables by their Primary keys (takes about 5s incl. `fetchall()`) based on `caseA-caseB pair` it receives.

Then it runs some analysis on the data and does `copy_from` to other two tables. The think is, the disk usage gets high over time and backlog peaks at `400s` and would eventually make my system stop.

I don't understand why it happens and how to prevent it? We are talking  altogether 65M case pairs. One result table will have same number of rows, but other will have much more - hundreds of million records.

I've tried playing around with `Semaphor` to control how many workers can download/upload, increased `work_mem`,`shared_buffers` etc. But it only seems to postpone the problem.

I implemented sleep time for all the workers after a couple of runs, but it does not seem to help, thats why I think the problem must be somewhere within postgres.

Many thanks for any help.